BzlMod + Golang = missing package and incorrect function
Trying to move my messy golang libraries over to bzlmod I found the rules_go reference, but was having trouble with external dependencies (I'd never used go.mod before and so prior stuff was messy).
In trying to learn some go/mod stuff and use that along with the bzlmod docs, I found the go modules tutorial and figured that would be a good start.
So I tried to follow that except for also including the MODULE.bazel and BUILD files as specified in the rules_go reference.
The end result was still:
INFO: Repository gazelle~~go_deps~com_bdl_greetings instantiated at:
  <builtin>: in <toplevel>
Repository rule go_repository defined at:
  D:/_bazel_out/5y5g3qvt/external/gazelle~/internal/go_repository.bzl:363:32: in <toplevel>
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'gazelle~~go_deps~com_bdl_greetings':                                                                                                             
   Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                     
        File "D:/_bazel_out/5y5g3qvt/external/gazelle~/internal/go_repository.bzl", line 282, column 13, in _go_repository_impl                                                                           
                fail("%s: %s" % (ctx.name, result.stderr))
Error in fail: gazelle~~go_deps~com_bdl_greetings: fetch_repo: read c:\projects\go\demos\greetings\bazel-bin: Incorrect function.
ERROR: no such package '@@gazelle~~go_deps~com_bdl_greetings//': gazelle~~go_deps~com_bdl_greetings: fetch_repo: read c:\projects\go\demos\greetings\bazel-bin: Incorrect function.
ERROR: C:/projects/go/demos/hello/BUILD:6:11: //:hello_lib depends on @@gazelle~~go_deps~com_bdl_greetings//:greetings in repository @@gazelle~~go_deps~com_bdl_greetings which failed to fetch. no such package '@@gazelle~~go_deps~com_bdl_greetings//': gazelle~~go_deps~com_bdl_greetings: fetch_repo: read c:\projects\go\demos\greetings\bazel-bin: Incorrect function.                                       
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:hello' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed                                                                                                                               
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.485s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.                                                                                                                                                                              
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully 

Which I find very confusing:

"no such package" seems wrong, since the package is clearly there.
"Incorrect function" just confuses me.

I'm not sure where to go from here.
Full code for my two little modules and more details at https://github.com/bdleitner/golang_bzlmod_demo
Please advise, I don't know what I'm missing.

Add something like this to your MODULE.bazel file:
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# rules_go
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

bazel_dep(name = "rules_go", version = "...") # TODO: define version here
bazel_dep(name = "gazelle", version = "...") # TODO: define version here

go_sdk = use_extension("@rules_go//go:extensions.bzl", "go_sdk")
go_sdk.download(
    name = "go_sdk",
    version = "1.22.5",
)
use_repo(go_sdk, "go_sdk")

register_toolchains("@go_sdk//:all")

go_deps = use_extension("@gazelle//:extensions.bzl", "go_deps")
go_deps.from_file(go_mod = "//:go.mod")

# All *direct* Go dependencies of the module have to be listed explicitly.
use_repo(
    go_deps,
    "com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2",
    "com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_config",
    "com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_feature_dynamodb_attributevalue",
    "com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_feature_dynamodb_expression",
    "com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_service_dynamodb",
    "com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_service_s3",
    "com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_service_secretsmanager",
    ...
)

Note that all direct Go dependencies of the module have to be listed explicitly (you do not need to list transitive dependencies).
In one of you top level BUILD.bazel files define:
load("@gazelle//:def.bzl", "gazelle")

gazelle(name = "gazelle")

go_library(
    name = "some_lib",
    srcs = ["lib.go"],
    importpath = "...",
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
    deps = [
        # Add needed deps here
        "@com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_service_dynamodb//:dynamodb",
    ],
)

To update dependencies to their latest available minor and patch versions:
go -- get -u ./...

Match the go.mod file with the dependencies required in the source files:
go -- mod tidy

Make sure Bazel build files match:
bazel run //:gazelle

Something like this should also work:
bazel run @rules_go//go -- get -u ./... # update dependencies to their latest available minor and patch versions
bazel run @rules_go//go -- mod tidy # match the go.mod file with the dependencies required in the source files
bazel run //:gazelle # make sure Bazel build files match


AFAICT, the difference between this and what I have is the manual selection of go sdk 1.22.5, in contrast with the 1.21.8 that the bazel run @rules_go... initialization did for me.
What's the significance of using 1.22.5 instead of 1.21.8 here?
